# How to reference maven jar to jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-2, extjs4

I have an ExtJS4 jar file under maven dependency(ie jar downloaded using pom). Now I need to use this extjs4 jar file in jsp page. How do i do this? Do i need to map this jar via a servlet in web.xml file? Any help would be appreciated. If possible could anyone provide sample example on what should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Copy extjs4 jar from your local maven repository (For example, under C:\Documents and Settings\User.m2\repository) and add it in your project.

Comment: i even tried that. I moved extjs4 jar into web-inf/lib folder. But still Extjs is not recognized. I even tried adding jar to class path via build path > add external jar . but no luck. any other suggesstion?